# How to delete all nested JSON objects?

Tags: python, json

JSON:

```
{
  "Profiles": [
    {
      "Name": "Test"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Test"
    }
  ]
}
```

The code I attempted to do this with:

```
with open(pathProfile, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
for profile in data['Profiles']:
    profile.pop()
with open(pathProfile, 'w+') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

This only deletes one of the profiles or objects. I'm looking to delete all.

Comment: What do you want at the end? `{"Profiles":[]}`? Something else? Note that the loop goes over the two `{"Name":"Test"}` dicts, so while it's interesting that `pop()`, without arguments, does not raise an error, it unlikely can do anything useful.

Comment: Use `data['Profiles'] = []`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just setting the value to an empty list to delete all the profiles:

```
import json

data = {
  "Profiles": [
    {
      "Name": "Test"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Test"
    }
  ]
}

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))

print("Deleting all profiles...")
data["Profiles"] = []

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "Profiles": [
    {
      "Name": "Test"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Test"
    }
  ]
}
Deleting all profiles...
{
  "Profiles": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be all you need for this specific task. Rather than iterating through and popping each object you could just replace it with an empty list:

```
data['Profiles'] = []
```